# Select search in 2 fields as if it were one

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select, sql-like

My table is:

```
Name | Surname
John    White
John    Red
```

I would like if I entered the name `John` it would list me all the first and last names that have the name John

for example

```
John White
John Red
```

For this the following instruction would suffice:

`SELECT surname, name FROM table WHERE name LIKE :keyword`

However, I would also like that if you continue to enter the surname `John R`

the record that was shown was:

`John Red`

in practice, in this select, I would like to treat the field `name` and `surname` as a single field

Answer (score 0):

You could use `concat()`:

```
SELECT surname, name 
FROM table 
WHERE CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) LIKE CONCAT('%', :keyword, '%')
```

This assumes that a single space is consistently used in `keyword` to separate the first and last name.

Note that I also added wildcards around the keyword, as it seems like they are not part of the parameter value.